# Type inference from right to left

Tags: scala

I created following code snippet:

```
class PimpToRight[A](f: A => Boolean) {
  def <| (a: A) = f(a)
}
implicit def f2pimp[A](f: A => Boolean) = new PimpToRight(f)

class PimpToLeft[A](a: A) {
  def <|: (f: A => Boolean) = f(a)
  def |> (f: A => Boolean) = f(a)
}
implicit def a2pimp[A](a: A) = new PimpToLeft(a)
```

There are right- and left-associative methods available.

Following code works:

```
((_: Int) > 3) <| 7
((_: Int) > 3) <|: 7
7 |> (_ > 3)
```

But this does not:

```
(_ > 3) <| 7
(_ > 3) <|: 7
```

Is it possible to infer type parameters from right to left?

Comment: I am surprised that there is a difference between, `(_ > 3) <|: 7` and `7.\`<|:\`(_ > 3)`, but indeed only the latter compiles. If you don't get an answer here, maybe ask on the mailing list or check the bug tracker?

Comment: @Kipton note that you can omit the back ticks if you place the `7` into parenthesis like this: `(7).<|:(_ > 3)`, since the compiler tries to invoke `<|:` on a `Double` `7.` without the parenthesis, which in turn leads to an infix invocation of `<|:` and that leads back to the type inference issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two issues are related: [SI-4773](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4773) and [SI-1980](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1980). Based on these issues, the answer to your question seems to be no. While not directly related to your question, there is a very nice post by Paul Chiusano on [making the most of type inference in Scala](http://pchiusano.blogspot.com/2011/05/making-most-of-scalas-extremely-limited.html), which addresses the current state of type inference in Scala and provides some useful advice.